# What's the meaning of the hashes at Enumerations?

Tags: c#, hash, enumeration, xml-documentation

I use `GhostDoc` for the XML-Documentation of my code, and it has a neat "auto-document"-function I use quite often, so now I used it on an enumeration and it came up with some strange hash-code I don't quite understand.

What is it for? Looks sort of like this:

`{35A90EBF-F421-44A3-BE3A-47C72AFE47FE}`

Comment: Would be a lot better question when you show the Guid in context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a String representation of a Guid. See the System.Guid type for more details.

Guids are essentially random codes (some types of Guids depend on MAC-Address or time though) which is so unlikely to occur again in this corner of SpaceTime that is can be considered to be unique in all Creation.

Comment: But why are they only added to `Enum`s and not to classes? Don't quite get the point... still, answer is correct I assume

Answer (score 2):

I just discovered the same, and I think it is a bug in GhostDoc. Funningly enough, it only happens (in my machine) when your enum values are all in the same line, i.e., something like this:

```
 enum GhostDocBug {
     Funny, Guid, Appearing
  }
```

If you put each value in its own line, it goes away